# Why this one approach when testing a component updates the mocked component successfully while the other one does not?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following test code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const TestComponent = ({}) => {
  const [isEvenOdd, setIsEvenOdd] = useState('Even')

  const isEven = (name) => name === 'Even'

  const doTheChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    return (isEven(isEvenOdd) ? setIsEvenOdd('Odd') : setIsEvenOdd('Even'))
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Button
        onClick={doTheChange}
        id="even-odd-button"
        message={`This number is **NOT**: ${isEven(isEvenOdd) ? 'odd' : 'even'}`} />
    </>
  )
}

export default TestComponent
```

Sorry if this code is a little confusing, but this is the best replication that I could do of a real code that I can't share here.

What this code does is:

1. There's a initial state setting the variable `isEvenOdd` to `Even`;
2. In this initial state, the `message` that is being passed as props to the `Button` is: "This number is **NOT**: odd";
3. After you click the button, the `isEvenOdd` state is changed to `Odd`;
4. Then the component re-renders and now the `message` props that is being passed to the `Button` is: "This number is **NOT**: even".

---

This code is working properly. The problem happens when I try to test this code. I'm using Enzyme and Jest for that.

The following test does **NOT** work:

```js
it('should change the message', () => {
  const component = shallow(<TestComponent />)

  component.find('#even-odd-button').invoke('onClick')({ preventDefault: jest.fn() })

  // This expectation fails. The result that I have here is: "'This number is **NOT**: odd'"
  // , which is the initial message.

  expect(component.find('#even-odd-button').prop('message')).toEqual('This number is **NOT**: even')
})
```

I searched a little bit here and there and tried that (the following test **WORKS**):

```js
it('should change the message', () => {
  const component = shallow(<TestComponent />)
  const button = component.find('#even-odd-button')

  button.invoke('onClick')({ preventDefault: jest.fn() })

  expect(button.prop('message')).toEqual('This number is **NOT**: even')
})
```

---

It seems to me that test no. 2 is keeping track of the updates that are happening in the component.

My question here is: Why is this not happening on test no. 1 as well?

What's the difference between using something like `component.find('#even-odd-button').invoke('onClick')({ preventDefault: jest.fn() })` and `button.invoke('onClick')({ preventDefault: jest.fn() })`?

Thank you!

Comment: What is `button` in the first test? I don't see that defined.

Comment: @srk It was a typo. Fixed it.